# How to set class with routing in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a master component that contain router-outlet
that is my master component

```
    <div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
```

and that is my routing.module

```
      {
    path: 'insuranceKindSample',
    component: InsuranceKindIndexSampleComponent,
    data: { title: ' آزمایش ثبت اطلاعات نوع بیمه', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: true, position: 'parent' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'master-dialog',
        component: InsuranceKindMasterDialogComponent,
        data: { title: 'Master-dialog', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: false },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'index',                             
            component: InsuranceKindIndexDialogComponent,
            data: { title: 'Index', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: false }
          },
          {
            path: 'add',
            component: InsuranceKindCreateSampleComponent,
            data: { title: 'Add', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: false }
          },
          {
            path: 'edit',
            component: InsuranceKindEditSampleComponent,
            data: { title: 'Edit', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: false }
          },
        ]
      },

    ]
  },
```

when the master component run,my index component is shown
that is my question: how can i add class to div that contain router-outlet when index is shown and then remove when rout change to add?

Comment: If I got it right, you want to add your class to something like the `<body>` tag, outside your app. Have you try using regular JavaScript to do it? You can react to the router navigation event and add the class to the element you want after retrieving it using any regular JavaScript DOM method (`document.findBy...` and others).

Comment: Thx for your answering, i added some of my code and explain it clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this as a best way:
1. in app-routing.module.ts i set a boolean property to index data named isIndexSliderDialog and set it ture

```
  {
    path: 'insuranceKindSample',
    component: InsuranceKindIndexSampleComponent,
    data: { title: ' آزمایش ثبت اطلاعات نوع بیمه', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: true, position: 'parent' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'master-dialog',
        component: InsuranceKindMasterDialogComponent,
        data: { title: 'Master-dialog', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: false },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'index',                            
            component: InsuranceKindIndexDialogComponent,
            data: { title: 'Index', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: false, isIndexSliderDialog: true }
          },
          {
            path: 'add',
            component: InsuranceKindCreateSampleComponent,
            data: { title: 'Add', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: false }
          },
          {
            path: 'edit',
            component: InsuranceKindEditSampleComponent,
            data: { title: 'Edit', icon: 'fa-bar-chart', showInMenu: false }
          },
        ]
      },

    ]
  },
```

2. then in Insurance-Kind-Master-Dialog.Component.ts i used lifecycle hooks, ngAfterViewInit() for checking component that load in router-outlet and get the property that i set in app-routing.module.ts

   ```
     ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.isIndexSliderDialog = this.route.firstChild.snapshot.data.isIndexSliderDialog;


   this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
     this.isIndexSliderDialog = this.route.firstChild.snapshot.data.isIndexSliderDialog;
   });
   ```

3.in Insurance-Kind-Master-Dialog.Component.html i used ngClass to set class1 to index and class2 to other routs:

```
<div [ngClass]="isIndexSliderDialog== true ? 'class1' : 'class2'">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a class to the div which contains router-outlet based on the route, you can use a conditional class attribute `ngClass`.

In the `app.component.html` add a `ngClass` which applies the indexClass when the url is '/index'

```
<div [ngClass]="url ? url + 'Class': ''">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

To get the current url when the url changes do the following in `app.component.ts` file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  url = '';

  constructor(private router: Router) {
       router.events.subscribe((route) => {
       if(route instanceof NavigationEnd){
          this.url = route.url;
          if(this.url && this.url.length > 0){
            this.url = this.url.slice(1);
          }
       }
    });
  }
}
```

Above code will capture the current url and save it on the url variable. The class will be changed accordingly to the route. if the route is index the class will be indexClass, if its add it will be addClass.

Here you can find the working example. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ultvh2)

Comment: tnx for your answering,exactly i used to try it but i need to get this url from routering.module directly for dynamic forms that's we can't give url manually for each form,so i need another way

Comment: what do you mean ? i dont quite get it

Comment: for this way [ngClass]="{myClass : router.url=='/index'}" is better but you see i should give the url manualy,i want to get it from routering dynamicly

Comment: for example we can use rout parameter like id that is get with rout path in app-routing.modul, i need something like this but for class name,do u get it?!

Comment: ur saying the classname should be dynamic?

Comment: Yes,class name and rout url

Comment: i think i got it, i have changed the answer and the example. Please check now. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ultvh2